# CSS InfoBox over all elements how to place?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I want that the blue box at [link](http://nitram0598.zapto.org/) is displayed the full width of the white area, the content...

code:

```
.info {
    background-color: #3498db;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

thank you for your help...

Comment: I can do it using JQuery.Should i post the code??

Comment: yes please it would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JQuery code:

```
var s=$('#content').width();
document.getElementById('home').style.width=s;
```

By using `Inspect Element` i found that **#content** is your parent(white background) div and **#home** is your div you want to adjust the width to the width of **#container**.

If its **info** class write:

```
var s=$('#content').width();
$('.info').css({'width':''+s+'px'});
```

Comment: no, the div with the `CLASS = "info"` i want to adjust..how with a class and not a div?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the width of 100%, this should be the full width of the content area...

Comment: no, don't work, then its over the whole page and more...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the blue content on 100% of #content, you should remove the padding on #content.